WalletConnect has recently been failing to connect on Swift iOS React Native
I have been using WalletConnect in my React Native app with Swift code, and it was working fine until recently. Now, it fails to connect and throws an error. Currently, it opens the MetaMask app, but the connect modal does not appear. Here is the code I am using. Could you please help me resolve this issue?
WaleltConnect.swift:
import Foundation
import WalletConnectSwift

protocol WalletConnectDelegate {
    func failedToConnect()
    func didConnect()
    func didDisconnect()
}

class WalletConnect {
    var client: Client!
    var session: Session!
    var delegate: WalletConnectDelegate

    let sessionKey = "sessionKey"

    init(delegate: WalletConnectDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func connect() -> String {
        // gnosis wc bridge: https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/
        // test bridge with latest protocol version: https://bridge.walletconnect.org
        let wcUrl =  WCURL(topic: UUID().uuidString,
                           bridgeURL: URL(string: "https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/")!,
                           key: try! randomKey())
        let clientMeta = Session.ClientMeta(name: "Habitnest",
                                            description: "WalletConnectSwift",
                                            icons: [URL(string: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1585/6091/files/Full_Logo_No_BG_1000x.png?v=1544223067")!, ],
                                            url: URL(string: "https://habitnest.com/")!)
        let dAppInfo = Session.DAppInfo(peerId: UUID().uuidString, peerMeta: clientMeta)
        client = Client(delegate: self, dAppInfo: dAppInfo)

        print("WalletConnect URL: \(wcUrl.absoluteString)")

        try! client.connect(to: wcUrl)
        return wcUrl.absoluteString
    }

    func reconnectIfNeeded() {
        if let oldSessionObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: sessionKey) as? Data,
            let session = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Session.self, from: oldSessionObject) {
            client = Client(delegate: self, dAppInfo: session.dAppInfo)
            try? client.reconnect(to: session)
        }
    }

    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes
    private func randomKey() throws -> String {
        var bytes = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 32)
        let status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytes.count, &bytes)
        if status == errSecSuccess {
            return Data(bytes: bytes, count: 32).toHexString()
        } else {
            // we don't care in the example app
            enum TestError: Error {
                case unknown
            }
            throw TestError.unknown
        }
    }
}

extension WalletConnect: ClientDelegate {
    func client(_ client: Client, didFailToConnect url: WCURL) {
        delegate.failedToConnect()
    }

    func client(_ client: Client, didConnect url: WCURL) {
        // do nothing
    }

    func client(_ client: Client, didConnect session: Session) {
        self.session = session
        let sessionData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(session)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sessionData, forKey: sessionKey)
        delegate.didConnect()
    }

    func client(_ client: Client, didDisconnect session: Session) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: sessionKey)
        delegate.didDisconnect()
    }

    func client(_ client: Client, didUpdate session: Session) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

Metamask to connect with react native
